# How do i remove the special chars that show as `\uxxx` in python3 string object?

Tags: python-3.x, regex, python-unicode

python string object as follow:

```
The site of the old observatory in Bern \u200bis the point of origin of the CH1903 coordinate system at 46°57′08.66″N 7°26′22.50″E\ufeff / \ufeff46.9524056°N 7.4395833°E\ufeff / 46.9524056; 7.4395833.
```

I want to remove these chars `\u200b` `\ufeff` that show as raw unicode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encode it to `ascii` and ignore errors

```
>>> s = 'The site of the old observatory in Bern \u200bis the point of origin of the CH1903 coordinate system at 46°57′08.66″N 7°26′22.50″E\ufeff / \ufeff46.9524056°N 7.4395833°E\ufeff / 46.9524056; 7.4395833'
>>> s.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
b'The site of the old observatory in Bern is the point of origin of the CH1903 coordinate system at 465708.66N 72622.50E / 46.9524056N 7.4395833E / 46.9524056; 7.4395833'
```

To replace unicode character with whitespace to keep the length same, you can use

```
#length of original string

>>> s = 'The site of the old observatory in Bern \u200bis the point of origin of the CH1903 coordinate system at 46°57′08.66″N 7°26′22.50″E\ufeff / \ufeff46.9524056°N 7.4395833°E\ufeff / 46.9524056; 7.4395833'
>>> len(s)
179

#to maintain the same length

>>> new_s = s.encode('ascii',errors='ignore').decode('utf-8')
>>> final_s = new_s + ' ' * (len(s) - len(new_s))
>>> final_s
'The site of the old observatory in Bern is the point of origin of the CH1903 coordinate system at 465708.66N 72622.50E / 46.9524056N 7.4395833E / 46.9524056; 7.4395833            '
>>> len(final_s)
179
```

this will add additional space at last to maintain the length

Comment: This works well, thank you for your help! If i would get the position of these special chars in the string, How can i do it?

Comment: In other words,I want to replace these characters with whitespace to keep the string length as the same

Comment: @merlin I have updated my answer, to maintain the length you can do something like this in the answer